# Google Bigtable-primarykey

Tags: google-app-engine

I know how to create table in google bigtable.My constriant is how to set primary key for my table using jpa.

Answer (score 0):

Bigtable is not a RDBMS. It does not have primary/foreign keys, constraints etc. you have key/value pairs, you can think of key's are primary key's since its already unique for a row. and value can be anything that you can serialize into a string.

Comment: ok but in this link they using primarykey
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html

as follows
@PrimaryKey
    private String name;